# Using dict with parameter

Tags: python

Is it possible to use a function with a dict argument which has other argument like `p2` in it?

```
def f(l, p2, p = {"t": p2}):
    print(l)

f(12, 13)
```

Comment: Well, does your code throw an error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p2' is not defined

Comment: Hi Karen, dont be sorry for asking questions, its what SO is for. That being said what are you trying to do? why not define `p` in the function. You need to explain what you are trying to do, what you expect output to be, and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The dict `{"t": p2}` is created at function definition, at which time `p2` is not bound to anything.

What you *can* do is

```
def f(l, p2, p=None):
    if p is None:
        p = {'t': p2}

    # rest of code
```